# PHP form only posts image to MYSQL database, no other values

Tags: php, mysql, image, forms

I am building a basic CMS. Today I wanted to add the option to upload a thumbnail image. I searched the internet and found a tutorial I could use. Now, after posting, the image uploads correctly and is displayed as it is supposed to be. All perfect.

The problem is now that my other form values don't get posted anymore.. Previously it worked fine, but after adding the option to upload thumbnails, no values get posted to the database except the image filename.

Anyone knows what's wrong with my code?

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form"> 

      <select name="category">
        <option value="option 1">option 1</option>
      </select>

      <input type="text"name="topic">

       <textarea name="article"></textarea>

      <select name="author">
         <option>option 1</option>
      </select>

      <input type="file" name="thumbnail">

     <button type="submit" name="post">Post article</button>

  </form>

<?php

function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
     {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
       switch($imagetype)
       {
           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
           case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';
           default: return false;
       }
     };

    $file_name=$_FILES["thumbnail"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["thumbnail"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["thumbnail"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
    $target_path = "../magazine/thumbnails/".$imagename;

if(isset($_POST['post']) && move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)){

    $username=mysqli_real_escape_string(db_conx,$_POST['author']);
    $topic=mysqli_real_escape_string(db_conx,$_POST['topic']);
    $article=mysqli_real_escape_string(db_conx,$_POST['article']);
    $category=mysqli_real_escape_string(db_conx,$_POST['category']);

   $result=mysqli_query($db_conx,"INSERT INTO articles (`username`,`topic`,`article`,`category`,`thumbnail`) VALUES('$username','$topic','$article','$category','$imagename')");

}

?>
```

Comment: I guess you mean $db_conx in your code? What is the result of print_r($_POST);?

Comment: Exactly, I meant $db_conx instead of db_conx, that fixed the problem. Thanks Andy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo. 
change this:

```
   <textarea name="article"</textarea>
```

to this:

```
   <textarea name="article"></textarea>
```

Another problem I see is your variable `db_conx`. you are missing the dollar sign `$`, which is **incorrect syntax**, unless you are referring to a constant. Change it to `$db_conx`.

Comment: Thanks, but that was just a typo when posting this questions. In my file it is correct. So the problem is somewhere else in my code..

Comment: where is `db_conx` defined?

Comment: That's defined in another file that is included in the header of this file. So my database connectionis working fine, as my image uploads and gets posted correctly. The only problem now is that my other form values don't get uploaded.It worked very well, until I added the file upload code..

Comment: besides that typo , your code seems fine. You need to implement error reporting and start debugging. What do you get when you use `var_dump($_POST)` before the `isset` condition

Comment: is it `db_conx` or `$db_conx`?

Comment: Oh, how stupid of me that I didn't see that! Indeed, that was the problem, I  forgot the $ before my first mysqli parameter db_conx ... Thank you so much, everything works perfectly now! :D

Comment: :) anytime. Glad I was able to help. Dont forget to accept the answer.